# Rectangle.Intersect(Rectangle). Is there a mistake in function?

Tags: c#

Trying to write programm that find intersection between many Rectangles. Trying to intersect example rectangles (x,y, width, height) - "2 5 5 3" and " 4 7 2 4", answer must be "4 5 2 2" but programm says to me that answer is "4 7 2 1" that can not be ! Please help me to find a mistake, i can not see it.
Code of my programm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProgramm
{
 class Rectangles
 {
    private List<Rectangle> List = new List<Rectangle>();

    public void AddRectangle(int X, int Y, int Width, int Height)
    {
        List.Add(new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height));
    }
    public int[] CrossRectangles()
    {
        if (List.Count != 0)
        {
            if (List.Count != 1)
            {
                Rectangle answer = List [0];
                for (int i = 1; i < List.Count; i++)
                    answer.Intersect(List[i]);
                return new int[] { answer.X, answer.Y, answer.Width, answer.Height };
            }else
                return new int[] { List.First().X, List.First().Y, List.First().Width, List.First().Height };
        }else 
            return new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    }
 }
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangles P = new Rectangles();

        P.AddRectangle(2, 5, 5, 3);
        P.AddRectangle(4, 7, 2, 4);

        foreach (int num in P.CrossRectangles())
            Console.WriteLine(num);

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you [debugged it](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? The problem shouldn't be hard to find if you step through in a debugger.

Comment: Of course, several times. But no one of them cant help me to find a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks correct to me.

Here's a graphical version:

```
 123456789   123456789   123456789
1.........  1.........  1.........
2.........  2.........  2.........
3.........  3.........  3.........
4.........  4.........  4.........
5.│││││...  5.........  5.│││││...
6.│││││...  6.........  6.│││││...
7.│││││...  7...──....  7.││┼┼│...
8.........  8...──....  8...──....
9.........  9...──....  9...──....
X.........  X...──....  X...──....
```

As you can plainly see, the intersection is indeed at coordinates {4, 7}, with dimensions 2x1.

Comment: ASCII art, really? :)

Comment: Why Y coordinate increases to down ?

Comment: @qqbenq: I switched to box-drawing characters; these aren't ASCII. user3472918: because that's how it usually goes both in text and in Paint. And on a Windows Form, too.

Comment: I was being sarcastic, but actually it's quite good that you included a 'picture', it makes it easier to imagine. Would be even better if it were a real picture :) +1

Comment: Guys, i really can not understand why my version is not good. Please take a look to this pic [link](http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1403/49/c94d74876890.jpg)

Comment: @Medinoc why Y axis is going down ?

Comment: @user3472918 Your rectangles are not drawn correctly. The first one "2 5 5 3" is a rectangle whose bottom left is (2,5) and whose top right is (7,8) in your coordinate system. For the second one those coordinates are (4,7) and (6,11). See this very answer for a graphical version. The actual direction of the Y axis is indifferent.

Comment: @user3472918 The problem with your drawing is that you extend the rectangle's `Height` *towards* zero instead of *away* from zero.

Answer (score 5):

The program is right, the good answer is "4 7 2 1".

Most likely you got confused with the second pair of parameters being width and height and not coordinates of the "top right" corner.

But draw the rectangles on a piece of paper and you will see that the answer is in fact "4 7 2 1".

Comment: Can I attach a picture? I figured the data rectangles on the coordinate plane. [link](http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1403/49/c94d74876890.jpg)

Comment: Of course you can. Make an edit to your question and attach the picture there.